# using the spread and/or dcast command

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
Name Type Date   Description   CorrectionCode
Bob  X1   01/01  Desc1            394
Bob  X2   01/01  Desc2            9348
Jim  X3   03/04  Desc4            934
```

How would I get that into

```
Name Type Date Description1 CorrectionCode1 Description2 CorrectionCode2
Bob   X1  01/01  Desc1          394           Desc2          9348
Jim   X3  03/04  Desc4           934
```

I'm trying to do this using spread `spread` in tidyR but am happy to use something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` ie. `v1.9.5`.  Instructions to install are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[, c('Type', 'Seq'):= list(Type[1L], 1:.N) , Name],
    Name+Type+Date~Seq, value.var=c('Description', 'CorrectionCode'))
#    Name Type  Date 1_Description 2_Description 1_CorrectionCode
#1:  Bob   X1 01/01         Desc1         Desc2              394
#2:  Jim   X3 03/04         Desc4            NA              934
#   2_CorrectionCode
#1:             9348
#2:               NA
```